# Conversion of raw data to R date/time class

Tags: r, date, datetime, posixct

I've successfully scraped a bunch of tables that I now want to manipulate in R. I'm new to R, but this seems like a good way to figure it out.

I currently have data stored in a bar-delimited CSV that looks like about this:

```
FIRST|LAST|9812036311|string-string|1999-07-06 00:00:00|2000-07-06 00:00:00|12345|1999-07-27 00:00:00|2,518.50
```

I can read it in with:

```
j <- read.table('my_data.csv', header = FALSE, sep = "|")
```

but ... how do I transform those date columns into dates that R can read?

Do I need to define a frame first?

Comment: I just needed as.Date I think: `j[[6]] <- as.Date(j[[6]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed `as.Date` -- as a sanity check, I created a new column with the modified date.

```
j$better.date <- as.Date(j$original.date, format="%Y-%d-%m")
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout `colclasses` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554572/read-csv-with-dates-and-numbers-with-r-statistical-software) to help R understand what type of data it should expect in each column of your CSV. Also look at the [lubridate](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lubridate/index.html) package for dealing with date formats.

Answer (score 1):

To convert date-time strings like you have, i suggest using the ***structure*** function, like so:

```
> # begin with date-time values stored as character vectors ("strings"):

> w
   [1] "2000-07-06 00:00:00"

> typeof(w)
   [1] "character"

> class(w)
   [1] "character"

> # use structure to convert them
> w = structure(w, class=c("POSIXt, POSIXct"))

> # verify that they are indeed R-recognizable date-time objects:
> w
   [1] "2000-07-06 00:00:00"
   attr(,"class")
   [1] "POSIXt, POSIXct"
```

w/r/t the mechanics: R functions are vectorized, so you can just pass in a column of dates and bind the result to the same column, like so:

```
> j$day
    [1] 1353967580 1353967581 1353967583 1353967584 1353967585 1353967586 
    [7] 1353967587 1353967588 1353967589 1353967590

> j$day = structure(day, class=c("POSIXt", "POSIXct"))

> day
   [1] "2012-11-26 14:06:20 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:21 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:22 PST"
   [4] "2012-11-26 14:06:23 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:24 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:25 PST"
   [7] "2012-11-26 14:06:26 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:28 PST" "2012-11-26 14:06:29 PST"
   [10] "2012-11-26 14:06:30 PST"
```

Comment: It may be instructive to inform the OP on the use of as.POSIXct as future conversions may not perfectly match the default format.