# To import date as date from csv in r

Tags: r

While importing a csv,the date column is imported as factor.Is there a way to import date as date and not factor,only while the import is being done

```
  Visits Visits2   Country     channel     date Visits3 spend     Margin...
1  11206   14106 Argentina Total Likes 01-01-12     106    99     0.056
2  11652   14552 Argentina Total Likes 01-02-12      87   107     0.057
3  12004   14904 Argentina Total Likes 01-03-12      89    97     0.077
4  12497   15397 Argentina Total Likes 01-04-12     101    98     0.030
5  12701   15601 Argentina Total Likes 01-05-12     101    87     0.098
```

Comment: What does your original csv data look like?

Comment: Visits Visits2   Country     channel     date Visits3 spend Margin...
1  11206   14106 Argentina Total Likes 01-01-12     106    99     0.056
2  11652   14552 Argentina Total Likes 01-02-12      87   107     0.057
3  12004   14904 Argentina Total Likes 01-03-12      89    97     0.077
4  12497   15397 Argentina Total Likes 01-04-12     101    98     0.030
5  12701   15601 Argentina Total Likes 01-05-12     101    87     0.098

Comment: Please add to the question  and format the text as it appears in a file, not by adding it to a comment, so people can read it.
I see no commas in your csv  (Comma Separated Values).

Comment: You may have another couple of problems. 1) Since you seem to be splitting on spaces not commas, you may have issues with countries, like the United Kingdom, which has spaces inside it.
2) You will need to know the locale of the dates, as laid out. They could either be US type mm-dd-yyyy or most of the rest of the world's dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: As of now the locales does not matter,may be if the date gets imported as date and not factor while importing in r,will work

Answer (score 0):

Try formating it like the standard **R** Date format,
and defining colClasses with read.csv2 like suggested here - [Read csv with dates and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554572/read-csv-with-dates-and-numbers)

Comment: Actually i want the date to be detected as detect during the import itself.